# How do you get the current date and time in bixby?

Tags: bixby

I am trying to access the current date and found the dates API. There seems to be a [method](https://bixbydevelopers.com/dev/docs/reference/JavaScriptAPI/dates#module_dates..Convenience%20method%20for%20creating%20a%20new%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%60dates.ZonedDateTime%60%20for%20the%20current%20date-time.%20%20An%20optional%20%60timeZoneId%60%20or%20%60geoPoint%60%20can%20be%20provided,%20otherwise%20the%20default%20user%20time%20zone%20is%20used.) all the way at the bottom of the docs that will return the current date and time just like I want but I think there is a typo. I tried guessing what the method name was with "datetime", "time", "now", "current", even the word "convenience" since that is the first word in the description of the method but none of these seemed to work. Any idea how to use this method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this `var currentTime = dates.ZonedDateTime.now().getDateTime();`

Thanks for raising this issue. We will raise internal visibility on this issue to document it better.